# cannot import Firestore fieldValue (existsSync is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-app, firebase-admin

I need to delete field in Firestore Document in my react app, [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) mentioned that I should use FieldValue from 'firebase-admin':

```
// Get the `FieldValue` object
var FieldValue = require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue;
```

but when I'm trying to get the FieldValue object like this, I get an error:

> TypeError: **existsSync is not a function**
>
> ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js/exports.find

I also saw some warnings in my console:

> ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
> 16:20-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression
>
> ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
> 16:20-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression
>
> ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
> 19:22-48 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression
>
> ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
> 19:22-48 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression
>
> ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
> 30:14-35 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression

what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firebase-admin node module is made for use in server-side node processes. You're trying to use it in a client-side React app, which is not going to work.

In client-side React you should use the regular Firebase JavaScript/Web SDK and use the code snippet from [that tab in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data):

> ```
> var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');
>
> // Remove the 'capital' field from the document
> var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
>     capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
> });
> ```